# This is a program for creating thread, but showing error can anyone suggest?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

[Thread Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRkcX.png)

This program is showing a error marked in the image as red underline. I cant understand that why it occurred. Can anyone suggest me anything?

Comment: Check what the error is! Look in the problems tab or hover over the underlined part or the X in the left bar.

Comment: If you had posted the code here as text, then someone could tell you immediately.

Comment: `new Thread1().new MyThread("First")`

Answer (score 0):

try to make the MyThread class static

`static class MyThread ...`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a compilation error because you are referring to a non-static member from static context.

add `static` before the class declaration

`static class MyThread extends Thread`